# Smooth function on $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am trying to prove that the function defined from $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ by $f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{x^{2}-1}}$ if $\vert x \vert \leq 1$  and $f(x)=0$ if $\vert x \vert > 1$ is a smooth function (that is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$) on $\mathbb R$. Does anyone knows how to prove that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** Show that for any integer $n$, on $(-1,1)$
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}\exp\left(\frac1{x^2-1}\right)
=\frac{P_n(x)}{Q_n(x)}\exp\left(\frac1{x^2-1}\right)
$$
Where $P_n$ and $Q_n$ are polynomials.

**Hint 2:** Show that for any integer $n$,
$$
\lim_{|x|\to1^-}\frac1{(x^2-1)^n}\exp\left(\frac1{x^2-1}\right)=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that $f$ is smooth on the whole $\mathbb R$ and that the problem may only be at $|x|=1$. Since the function is also symmetric, you only have to prove smoothness for $x=1$.

For $x=1$, look at the limit of $f^{(n)}(x)$ when $x$ approaches zero from the left. It must be $0$ as that is the limit from the right. The difficult thing is to calculate the function $f^{(n)}$. Try calculating $f', f''$, maybe even $f'''$ and try to find some pattern.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, nevertheless, the computations are quite heavy. Thanks.